# How to prove the property of slowly varying function ''$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^{-\delta}L(x)=0$ for any $\delta>0$"?

Tags: real-analysis, slowly-varying-functions

As we kown, a positive function $L: [0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is called slowly varying function if
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{L(cx)}{L(x)}=1 \text{ for any $c>0$}. $$

I find the property of slowly varying function ''$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^{-\delta}L(x)=0$ for any $\delta>0$" is very important. This property
is published in Russian, in 1965.  Can you give me its proof in English? I am very eager to know its strict mathematical proof.

Comment: Have you looked at Volume 2 of Feller's book?

Comment: I known this book, but I do not have it. Can the proof I wnated be found in this book?

Comment: Feller proves a strong result: $L$ is slowly varying at $\infty$ if and only if $L(x)=f(x)e^{\int_1^{x} \frac {g(y)} ydy}$ where $f(x)$  tends to a finite limit at $\infty$ and $g(x) \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty$.  Your assertion is an easy consequence of this.

Comment: Could you give me a strict proof about your ''easy consequence"?

Comment: Thank you! I kown how to prove this ''easy consequence" by using the simple result $a=e^{\text{ln}a}$.

Comment: Seneta's book on Regularly Varying Functions is another useful reference.